# SPSearchJobDefinition error after migrating to new domain

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, error

I've moved our sharepoint server (MOSS 2007) from one domain to another following [this procedure](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao1/archive/2011/03/17/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another.aspx).

Everything seems to work OK but I've getting the error below in the event logs every five minutes. It seems pretty obvious that there's a service or job configured to use an account somewhere from the old domain but I'm damned if I can spot where. Can anybody help?

> The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SPSearchJobDefinition (ID bd8cb4b6-d067-4053-a303-39b22fc1940e) threw an exception. More information is included below.
>
> The specified account information is incorrect or not valid.  Check that the correct account and password are being used.

We used to have a three domain setup, sharepoint server was in domain A, which had trusts with domains B and C. The server has been moved to domain B which now has a trust set with C.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run

stsadm.exe -o spsearch -farmcontentaccessaccount newdomain\contentaccount -farmcontentaccesspassword NewPassword